# How to fix this keyboard bug in Minecraft?

Tags: 18.04, java, games, minecraft

After a while of not playing Minecraft I reinstalled it on my Ubuntu machine. I created my creative world and everything seemed to be fine. However, when the world loaded in, I couldn't move at all. I tried to change between different keyboard layouts, but that didn't help. I decided to go into the controls menu to change my walking keys manually to WASD. That did something, because when I pressed "W" I did walk forward. However, when I released the key I didn't seem to stop. Only when spamming the WASD did I stop, but that would render the keys unusable again and I would have to set the keys again manually to WASD to move a little bit. I suspect that this is an Ubuntu or Java issue. I am using a non US keyboard.

EDIT: I have been testing this in 1.12.2, and when I tested it in 1.14.4 it was working properly. I prefer 1.12.2, so would it be possible to somehow fix this bug and be able to play with that version?

Comment: Hmmm. Unable to duplicate on my Ubuntu Minecraft install. Mine works properly.

Comment: Only way to deal with this is `setxkbmap us`

Answer (score 0):

move the us keyboard layout to the top of the layouts list (keyboard settings -> keyboard layouts)
so UBUNTU will know that the us layout is "standart".